# Parse content from select menu, Python+BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, urllib2

I am trying to parse data from a page using python which can be pretty straightforward but all the data is hidden under jquery elements and such which makes it harder to grab the data. Please forgive me as i am a newbie to Python and programming as a whole so still getting familiar with it.The website i am getting it from is http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series so i just need all the data from the E This is the code i have so far:

```
import string, urllib2, csv, urlparse, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

changable_url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All%20In%20One/E%20Series'
page = urllib2.urlopen(changable_url)
base_url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

redirects = []
model_info = []

select = soup.find(id='myselectListModel')
print select.get_text()


options = select.findAll('option')

for option in options:
    if(option.has_attr('redirectvalue')):
       redirects.append(option['redirectvalue'])

for r in redirects:
    rpage = urllib2.urlopen(base_url + r.replace(' ', '%20'))
    s = BeautifulSoup(rpage)
    print s

    sys.exit()
```

However the only problem is, it just prints out the data for the first model which is
Asus->All In One->E Series->ET10B->AC Adapter. The actual HTML page prints out like the [following...](http://codepad.org/3f4GEdJb) (output was too long - just pasted the main output needed)

I am unsure on how i would grab the data for all the E Series parts as i assumed this would grab everything? Also i would appreciate if any answers you show relate to the current method i am using as this is the way the person in charge would like it done, Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

This is how i am trying to parse the HTML:

```
for r in redirects:
    rpage = urllib2.urlopen(urljoin(base_url, quote(r)))
    s = BeautifulSoup(rpage)
    print s

    data = soup.find(id='accordion')

    selection = data.findAll('td')

    for s in selections:
        if(selection.has_attr('class', 'ProduktLista')):
            redirects.append(td['class', 'ProduktLista'])
```

This is the error i come up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\asus.py", line 31, in <module>
    selection = data.findAll('td')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Comment: You have a `sys.exit()` *inside* the `for r in redirects` loop, so it's no wonder only the first model page is printed. Start by not using `sys.exit()`.

Comment: With the `sys.exit()` removed your script spews all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `sys.exit()` call you have in your loop:

```
for r in redirects:
    rpage = urllib2.urlopen(base_url + r.replace(' ', '%20'))
    s = BeautifulSoup(rpage)
    print s

    # sys.exit()  # remove this line, no need to exit your program
```

You also may want to use `urllib.quote` to properly quote the URLs you get from the option dropdown; this removes the need to manually replace spaces with `'%20'`. Use `urlparse.urljoin()` to construct the final URL:

```
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import 

for r in redirects:
    rpage = urllib2.urlopen(urljoin(base_url, quote(r)))
    s = BeautifulSoup(rpage)
    print s
```

Comment: Ahh yes thanks.. that shows all the data for the AC ADAPTER but it does not show the data for all the remaining categories? Such as Brackets, Cables etc. The Edit above shows how i have coded this however i come up with an error described above

Comment: @ash: Whenever you see a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'` exception, that means the *previous* search didn't return any results. `soup.find(id='accordion')` in this case doesn't return anything, so check the pages you are loading.

Comment: I noticed it is just getting the data from the outside default page rather than when it loads the page displaying all the categories such as the Brackets, Cables, etc. Because the new table appears once the final drop down has been selected. How would i find the data once the table appears?

Comment: @ash: Most likely the page uses JavaScript and AJAX to load new data. Use your browser Developer tools to observe what URLs the page loads over AJAX, then replicate that in your script.

Comment: I think i am starting to get the gist of it now. So essentially i would have to create a new soup for when the the table is loaded?

Comment: @ash: That depends on what the AJAX call returns; some sites use JSON for example, others just load a new HTML page from the server and use that. If HTML is loaded with AJAX, then you can BeautifulSoup that HTML too.

Comment: Yes html is loaded with AJAX, it is rather strange because before i try to gather the data and when it shows the output for the page it DOES show all the data held within the AJAX inside the div tag named `accordion` so i dont understand when i find that, it doesn't display anything?

Comment: I use the following `data = soup.find(id='accordion')
    print data` but it prints out `None`?

Comment: So there is no `id='accordion'` in your HTML.

Comment: But when i print out the `for r in redirects` loop, the HTML outputs `id=accordion`? so i add `data = soup.find(id=''accordion) print data` after the last line in that loop which should return?

Comment: @ash: Perhaps not *all* pages have it?

Comment: What do you mean? So how would i grab this data?